# Typescript definition for a constructor on a static class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to write a type definition for the following code. I guess the best way to describe it is a static class that contains a named constructor.

```
var ajaxAdapter = new IAjaxAdapter.implement({
   ajax: function (work: IAjaxRequest) {
      ...
   }
}
```

But I'm getting an build error `Property 'implement' does not exist on type 'typeof IAjaxAdapter'`.

My d.ts looks like this right now but obviously it's a bit wrong

```
export class IAjaxAdapterInstance {
    constructor(any: any);
    ajax: (request: IAjaxRequest) => void;
}
export class IAjaxAdapter {
    implement: IAjaxAdapterInstance;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, if not I guess I could any type it... but I was hoping for something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the types, since you're using `implement` as a static property that refers to a class rather than an object, it should type if you add a `static` and a `typeof`:

```
export class IAjaxAdapter {
    static implement: typeof IAjaxAdapterInstance;
}
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Also, I had no idea you could use static and typeof in a definition file, yay learning!